# JSON required property vs unrecognized

Tags: java, json

My java Object has the following JSON property:

```
@JsonProperty(required = true)
private String taxGroupingId;
```

I have not added `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to the java object/class.

The JSON message looks like this:

```
{"taxPayerId":27667865,"SSN":"384732897687639","taxPayerName":"ABS","taxPayerId":"23203948"}
```

Now the exception thrown is an `Unrecognized field "taxPayerId"` but what I would expect is an exception related to the "Required field missing".
Which property should I use to get the desired exception?

```
package com.usps.data.pricing.vo;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;


public class TaxValuation {

    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private String taxGroupingId;

    private String SSN;

    private String taxPayerName;

    private String taxPayerId;

    /**
     * @return the taxGroupingId
     */
    public String getTaxGroupingId() {
        return taxGroupingId;
    }

    /**
     * @param taxGroupingId the taxGroupingId to set
     */
    public void setTaxGroupingId(String taxGroupingId) {
        this.taxGroupingId = taxGroupingId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the sSN
     */
    public String getSSN() {
        return SSN;
    }

    /**
     * @param sSN the sSN to set
     */
    public void setSSN(String sSN) {
        SSN = sSN;
    }

    /**
     * @return the taxPayerName
     */
    public String getTaxPayerName() {
        return taxPayerName;
    }

    /**
     * @param taxPayerName the taxPayerName to set
     */
    public void setTaxPayerName(String taxPayerName) {
        this.taxPayerName = taxPayerName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the taxPayerId
     */
    public String getTaxPayerId() {
        return taxPayerId;
    }

    /**
     * @param taxPayerId the taxPayerId to set
     */
    public void setTaxPayerId(String taxPayerId) {
        this.taxPayerId = taxPayerId;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding @JsonDeserialize to the class.

Comment: I want to get the "required field" exception meaning, taxGroupingId is required but not sent. 
I understand 'taxPayerId' is not part of the JSOn object so getting unrecognised field exception. My question was how to get the exception for mandatory field.

Comment: you should include your whole class for clarity. not a snippet. but based on the error you should follow the last line of my answer & also getters & setters for that field & it should fix it.

but please, for clarity, edit this question to include the whole class.

Comment: Updated the class. Bascially have not given the @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true), so it shows me the ' Unrecognized field "taxPayerId"' which is totally fine.
But my question is since i had given taxGroupingId as -> required, i would expect a different exception for that.

Answer (score 0):

> I have not given @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) to the java object/class

While the documentation of `ignoreUnknown` uses a bit [cryptic wording](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#ignoreUnknown()), it still says that the default behaviour is to throw the exception you see, upon encountering an unknown field. Since "taxPayerId" is the very first thing the parser encounters, it just throws the exception.
Checking for the presence of all required fields could take place after finishing to parse the object, in a state which the parser simply does not reach with your current code.